# Showing a jQuery popup before browser window closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, onbeforeunload

I'm using the following js to show a popup before the browser/window closes. But it does not seem to be working.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    $('#beforeclose').click(); 
});
```

The popup i'm trying to show is [prettyPopin](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettypopin/) . And the `#beforeclose` is the id of the anchor with which i'm trying to bind the click event before the window unloads. I have noticed that native js popups work but the jQuery popup does not work.

Is there a way to achieve what i want to? Please do explain to me or refer me to the respective link because i'm not an expert at js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot safely do that.

`onbeforeunload` is designed in a way to avoid completely preventing the user from leaving your page. The only thing you should do is return a string with a message why the user might not want to leave the page. This message is displayed to the user [unless he's using firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641509).

Comment: Can we do this any other way? Please suggest.

Comment: No. If you could it would defeat the purpose of those restrictions, wouldn't it?

Comment: So am i right to comprehend that only native js alerts can stop the execution of even flow? And there is no way a custom popup can do that? Just making things clear for myself ;)

Comment: Correct. And at least firefox is going to disable `alert()` etc during this event since it's kind of inappropriate there.

Comment: can you share code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        function confirmmsg() {
            return "Mail Not sent";
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmmsg;

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    $('#beforeclose').click(); 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; // just in case.. 
});
```

from [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

> event.preventDefault()
>
> **Description**: If this method is called, the default action of the event
>   will not be triggered.

Basically, you are binding the function that shows the popup on the `beforeunload` event, but that does not block the browser like an alert window or something like that. Using `event.preventDefault()` you will stop the execution of event flow.

Comment: `beforeunload` doesn't work like this. You can only return a string that might (not firefox) or might not (firefox) be shown to the user in a prompt if he wants to leave the page or not.

Comment: Thanx man returning something stops the window from closing . but with a message telling me if i want to leave the page or no ... I don't want that message. I just want my jquery popup . Please do tell me if there is a way..

Comment: See my answer. you cannot do that.

Comment: @ThiefMaster what other way is there or can we even achieve this?

Comment: I have writen that code on an assumption. Apparently it cannot be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own